# Encripting the data between web-application and the server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, encryption

I'd like to avoid of using of the API by anybody except my web-application.

I could encrypt the data sending to server via post requests and decrypt the responses of the API's server. But hacker can dig into the web-page code and simulate the web-page behavior and make harm to the server (for example by spamming one).

I could [uglyfy](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs) JS code but can I consider that it is enough for applications not as secured as bank? Probably I missed any easy and beautiful solution?

Comment: Can you change the settings with your host to only allow calls to the api from certain domains or IP addresses?

Comment: No, @KevBot. Web application can be run by any user at any IP.

Comment: There already is a solution for that: ssl / https

Comment: @jeroen, I thought that the implementation is not so easy. Anyway thank you for the idea I will read a bit more about it. However I'd like to avoid any unnecessary complication.

Comment: I think it's the only secure solution. You can get free certificates if you don't sell things on your site and installation is not that hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But hacker can dig into the web-page code and simulate the web-page behavior and make harm to the server (for example by spamming one).

#### [This is an unavoidable truth about client-server applications](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/03/client-authenticity-is-not-server-s-problem)!

You cannot prevent a dedicated reverse engineers from simulating your client-side application. It's a fool's errand to try.

Instead, architect your products to ensure server-side data maintains its integrity even if the client-side application is inauthentic.